# Can someone help me fix this water level controller?

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, bjt

[image: Water Level Circuit]
A, B and C are the prongs that stick into the water at 1/4, half and full respectively. D is used to provide the current to switch on each of the prongs as the come in contact with the water.

That all works fine but when the motor part is introduced it does not work as it should. When the water level is at A this is meant to be turn on the motor by turning on Q1 which should allow sufficient voltage to turn on the IRF3205 MOSFET. When C is turned on this should allow the power in the MOSFET to discharge and turn it off. But none of this happens, instead, D1 and D2 light up suggesting that something has gone wrong. Could someone please help?

---

Update:

I have added in the resistors and the BJTs are still BC635 and the MOSFET is still an IRF3205

---

Update 3:

[image]
I have changed where the base is connected and I think this would work @transistor

Comment: Update 3 ties both bases to ground. They can never turn on now. :^(

Comment: Please don't replace the original schematic with update 3 as it makes my answer irrelevant and will confuse future readers. Put the original back. You also need to name the  components on your new schematics.

Comment: This is quite a mess now, since no one will ever know what A, B, C, and D are without tediously looking at previous edits.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

1. You have no current limiting resistors in the LEDs. They should burn out when Q3, 4 and 5 turn on.
2. You have no current limiting resistors in the bases of Q1 and 2. This means that they are both turned on via D1 and D3 when the probes are dry and have almost no current limits other than the LEDs. This won't last long.
3. If you were able to get Q1 and Q2 to turn off there is no discharge path for M1. You need to pull it high or low but not let it float.
4. If both Q1 and Q2 are on what do you expect to happen to the gate of M1?

Fixes:

1. Calculate the required current limiting resistor values for D1, 2 and 3 and add them in.
2. Add base resistors for Q1 and 2. 1k would be fine.
3. Figure out how you're going to prevent the gate of M1 from floating and do it!

That looks like a CircuitLab schematic. There's a button on the editor toolbar to allow you to embed a schematic. That makes it easy for us to copy and paste into our answers and modify.

Modify the design (leaving some history in your original post so future readers can make sense of comments and answers) and put it into your original post.

---

Update 1.

[image]

*Figure 1. Current path when transistors A, B and C turned off. LEDs A and C turn on.*

Draw a truth table of what you require:

*Table 1. Logic for outputs based on inputs A, B and C.*

```
| A | B | C || D1 | D2 | D3 | Motor |
=====================================
| 0 | 0 | 0 || Off| Off| Off| On    |
| 1 | 0 | 0 || On | Off| Off| On    |
| 1 | 1 | 0 || On | On | Off| On    |
| 1 | 1 | 1 || On | On | On | Off   |
=====================================
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the 2.2K ohm resistors into the schematic for the LEDs and I didn't use base resistors on Q1 and Q2 because I thought that the current would be brought down sufficiently by these resistors. @transistor

Comment: OK. Fix the schematic then. We can't debug an incorrect schematic.

Comment: I have posted the improved circuit in an answer @transistor

Comment: See update. You have more figuring out to do.

Comment: Hint: if my Table 1 is correct what change in conditions determine whether the motor should run or not? That's the only thing you need to monitor for motor control.